# How to save the data in the text file in column format alone?

Tags: c#, user-interface, richtextbox

I've a gui and I get temperature data from a Uc. I can see the data in the rich text box and save to a text file. But I cannot understand how to sort the saved data in the column format. Right now it is a long row of data. Please advice.

Would it be advisable to replace the rich text box to a normal text box?

I've a button to save data to the text file (button3_Click);

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
namespace Serial_receive
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // All members variables should be placed here
        // make it more readable, hopefully!
        string t;
        SerialPort sp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            // User can already search for ports when the constructor of the FORM1 is calling 
            // And let the user search ports again with a click
            // Searching for ports function

            SearchPorts();
        }
       //search button  
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            SearchPorts();
        }
        void SearchPorts()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Catch exception if it will be thrown so the user will see it in a message box
            OpenCloseSerial();
        }      
        void OpenCloseSerial()
        {
            try
            {
                if (sp == null || sp.IsOpen == false)
                {
                    t = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                    sErial(t);
                    button2.Text = "Close Serial port"; // button text
                }
                else
                {
                    sp.Close();
                    button2.Text = "Connect and wait for inputs";   // button text

                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)   // catching error message
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);   // displaying error message
            }           
        }

        void sErial(string Port_name)
        {
            try
            {
                sp = new SerialPort(Port_name, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);   // serial port parameters
                sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                sp.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw (new SystemException(err.Message));
            }
        }
//
        private  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            // This below line is not need , sp is global (belongs to the class!!)
            //SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
            {
                if (sp.IsOpen)
                {
                    string w = sp.ReadExisting();
                    if (w != String.Empty)
                    {
                        Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(w)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sp == null || sp.IsOpen == false)
            {
                OpenCloseSerial();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Serial Channel to FRDM-KW40Z";
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\varman\Documents\";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string temperature = "Temperature";
                string sorted = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(temperature, Environment.NewLine + temperature);
                sorted = sorted.Substring(sorted.IndexOf(temperature));
                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, sorted);
                Text += "\r\n";
                richTextBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             richTextBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code that set text in the RichTextBox to the question? Because in this part you need to add `Environment.NewLine` before adding a new of temperature.

Comment: would you like to have the text sorted in the RichTextBox? in the output file? both?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to sort it only in the output file because you didn't share the code that change `richTextBox1.Text.`

So you can add a new line for each temperature before writing to the file:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string temperature = "Temperature";
            string sorted = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(temperature, Environment.NewLine + temperature);
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, sorted);
            Text += "\r\n";
            richTextBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Add this line of code before `File.WriteAllText` if you want to write the text that starts with "Temperature" (this way you remove the "?????" at the beginning):

```
 sorted = sorted.Substring(sorted.IndexOf(temperature));
```

**EDIT:** 
Following your last edit - you added the code that updates the RichTextBox. So you can do the sorting by column only in `DataReceivedHandler`. See below:

```
private  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

            if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars || !sp.IsOpen)
            {
               return;
            }

            string w = sp.ReadExisting();

            if (w != String.Empty)
            {
                string temperature = "Temperature";
                string sorted = w.Replace(temperature, Environment.NewLine + temperature);
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(sorted)));
            }
}
```

Basically what you need to understand is that `File.WriteAllText(fileName, input)` is where you write `input` into the file, so you can manipulate `input` as you wish before that line. If you wish to alter the text before it's dispalyed in the `RichTextBox` then you need to see where you execute something like `richTextBox1.AppendText(input)` or `richTextBox1.Text = input` and do all the changes you want on `input` before that line.

Comment: thank you very much. I understand now. But this is not universal, is it? I mean, this method sorts the output based on the string Temperature I believe. Or does this hold true for any input that is saved from the textbox? Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, also with this approach I can't see the data in the richTextBox anymore. But I can sure get the processed data. Any advice? :)

Comment: If you don't won't to clear the text in the RichTextBox then don't set the file name at the end when saving. And you are right, the code assumes you want to split the text based on "Temperature". If you want to sort also the RichTextBox you need to share the code that fill it.

Comment: I've included the complete code. Please let me know. Thanks @KernelMode :)

Comment: Hi, So I have moved just "Text += "\r\n";" into the DataReceivedHandler (still hoping it would format data universally). It works I suppose. But strangely I don't see the values in the text box anymore! I can't understand why. Any suggestion @KernelMode?

Comment: Nope! It doesn't work at all. So much for working universally :(

Comment: you are deleting all the content of `RichTextBox` when you assign something to `Text` property like you do here: `richTextBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;`. Remove that line if you want to keep the content. Use `richTextBox1.Append()' to add content and not reseting `richTextBox1'

Comment: And why you need `Text += "\r\n";`?

Comment: to add a new line after every data entry! Is it possible to save any content from the text box to the text (regardless of string) file in the required format? I can't wrap my hear around it. Please let me know if you have a way. Good day.

Comment: Are you asking to split text (to lines) by `word` when `word` is unknown? you must know how you split before you split :) You can get `word` as parameter or from some input but you must have it.

Comment: That's exactly what I need :( This gets hopeless by the minute!

Comment: If you don't know what is the value of `word` but you know what is the maximum length of a line then it is posilsible to sort anyway.